# cannot access json object property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am accessing a key from json object but it returns undefined

```
{"body":"Hi","date":"2016-07-29 07:43:00"}

var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.txt));
console.log(a.body)

//undefined
```

value of r is

```
{
  username: '1',
  txt: '{"body":"Hi","date":"2016-07-29 07:43:00"}',
 }
```

I have tried using stringify and then parse to json but still return undefined.

Comment: share value of `r`

Comment: if `r` is the object remove `.txt` and it will work  https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/158/

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I have shared the value

Comment: @JN_newbie `var a = JSON.parse(r.txt);` , it's already a json string no need to stringify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've to parse your `json` like this. Ensure that your whatever input you're giving to JSON.parse, it should be a string.

You can run the below snippet to ensure that it's working and giving output `Hi`.

```js
var json = '{"body":"Hi","date":"2016-07-29 07:43:00"}';

var a = JSON.parse(json);
document.write(a.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code stringified result would be `"\"{\"body\":\"Hi\",\"date\":\"2016-07-29 07:43:00\"}\""`(which is valid string representation in JSON), parsing it would again provide the string as result not the object. When you were trying to get `body` property of string which will be `undefined` since there is no property like `body` for a string.

So there is no need to stringify a JSON string again just avoiding the stringify method  would make it work.

```js
var r = {
  username: '1',
  txt: '{"body":"Hi","date":"2016-07-29 07:43:00"}',
}; 

// parse the JSON string and get the object
var a = JSON.parse(r.txt);

console.log(a.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove single quote in r.txt and it should work

Here is the code I updated :

```
var r = {
  username: '1',
  txt: {"body":"Hi","date":"2016-07-29 07:43:00"},
 };

var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r.txt));
console.log(a.body)
```

If `r.txt` is `string` you only need parse it. If it's an `object`, you will convert it to string by `stringify` then `parse` it